# how does " . ./filename " command work

Tags: linux, bash, shell, dot-source

I was following a tutorial on openvpn and it needed to execute a command `. ./vars`.  It displays a message. On reading the file I found that it executes a echo command in file and disregards everything else in file. On adding other echo statement, it also gets executed. So i would like some basic explanation on this. Is this something related to bash only?

Comment: This might help: `help .`

Comment: It is possible to use `.` (`source`) builtin bash command without full or relative path to file: `. vars` but in such case `.` command does searching of its argument in directories listed in `$PATH` variable. When your file has name which can be used in some system bin directory, wrong file can be selected: `. echo` or `. ./echo`.

Comment: I think that disregarded lines look like `dir="/home/someone"`. These lines are not disregarded (lines starting with a `#` are skipped, they are comments), but executed: It will give the `var` with the name `dir` the value on the right side of `=` (no spaces around `=`). You can try `echo "me=${me}"; me=Anmol; echo "me=${me}"`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

`.` and `source` are synonymous: it just runs the file line-by-line in the current shell. `./vars` is just a path to some file named `vars` in the current directory. So all that command does is run the file `vars` line-by-line.

As for the rest of your question, I don't really understand what you're asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that `source` is an (optional) synonym for `.`, since `.` is the canonical name for the command. (See [posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot).)

Answer (score 0):

The `.` at the start has an explanation [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232932/in-a-bash-script-what-does-a-dot-followed-by-a-space-and-then-a-path-mean), and the `./filename` is a relative reference to the file.

Answer (score 0):

`.` sources or imports a bash script to the current script you are working on ( if you are creating a script ) or to the current tty ( terminal  or command line ) if you are working with the commandline interface. The script it is sourcing must be an executable ( it should have the -x flag set )

`./filename` means find filename in the present directory am in. if you execute only  `./filename` in tty  ( terminal  or command line ) or inside a script, it finds filename and check if filename is executable, then it runs filename . You should take not that `./` means the present working directory. Using two dots ( `../filename` ) instead of one with filename tells the bash parser go to the previous directory before the present one am in

using `. ./filename` you are telling the bash parser to import or source (`.`) filename (./filename ) in the directory you are currently on